# ¿Por qué al pulsar en un elemento del recyclerview me devuelve un -1?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, app

Tengo una app para **android (Kotlin)** que muestra una lista de elementos obtenida mediante Json, el problema es que al pulsar en cualquiera de los items de la lista, me devuelve un -1, cuando en realidad quiero que me devuelva la posición del item dentro de la lista de objetos.

He creado en el adapter del recycler un elemento llamado **itemClickHandler** que recibe un entero y no devuelve nada: **val itemClickHandler: (Int) -> Unit**.
Luego, en la función **onCreateViewHolder** del adapter tengo una vista creada con una referencia al **viewHolder** inicializada con esta vista: **var viewHolder = AmiiboViewHolder(v)**. Con estas dos variables creadas, he hecho llamado a mi **itemClickHandler** utilizando la función invoke a la que le paso el adaptador en el que estoy, quedando así:

```
v.setOnClickListener {
    itemClickHandler.invoke(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
}
```

Y lo he implementado así en mi código, este es el **adapter**:

```
class AmiiboAdapter (var miContext: Context, var listaAmiibos: ArrayList<Amiibo>, val itemClickHandler: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<AmiiboAdapter.AmiiboViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener{

    class AmiiboViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var miImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem)
        var miTextViewSerie2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemSerie2)
        var miTextViewCharacter2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemCharacter2)
        var miTextViewSaga2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemSaga2)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AmiiboViewHolder {
        var v: View = LayoutInflater.from(miContext).inflate(R.layout.amiibo_item, parent, false)

        var viewHolder = AmiiboViewHolder(v)

        v.setOnClickListener{
            itemClickHandler.invoke(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }

        return AmiiboViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AmiiboViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val amiibo: Amiibo = listaAmiibos.get(position)

        var imageUrl: String = amiibo.image
        var serie: String = amiibo.serie
        var character: String = amiibo.character
        var game: String = amiibo.saga

        holder.miTextViewSerie2.setText("$serie")
        holder.miTextViewCharacter2.setText("$character")
        holder.miTextViewSaga2.setText("$game")
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.miImageView)
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el tamaño de la lista
     */
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listaAmiibos.size
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    }
}
```

Y este es mi código en el **main**. Tengo una función llamada parseJson() que se encarga de llenar la lista. En el main estoy creando una función a la que tengo que pasarle el adapter. Yo la he llamado **onItemClickHandler**, esta función recibe la posición del elemento que se ha pulsado. Al inicializar el adapter, queda así: **adapter = AmiiboAdapter(applicationContext, listaAmiibos, this@MainActivity::onItemClickHandler)**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var listaAmiibos: ArrayList<Amiibo>
lateinit var miRecycler: RecyclerView
lateinit var miRequest: RequestQueue
lateinit var adapter: AmiiboAdapter
lateinit var miTextViewTotal2: TextView
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Lista donde se guardan los Amiibos
        listaAmiibos = ArrayList<Amiibo>()

        miRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        adapter = AmiiboAdapter(applicationContext, listaAmiibos, this@MainActivity::onItemClickHandler)      
    }

    /**
     * Función que muestra la posición del elemento que hemos pulsado en la lista.
     */
    private fun onItemClickHandler(position: Int){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    /**
     * Función que llena la lista conectando mediante json
     */ 
    private fun parseJson(){
        ...
    }
```

En el toast de la función **onItemClickHandler** del main me muestra un -1 cuando pulso en cualquier elemento de la lista del recycler.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate que en el método onBindViewHolder() del adapter ya tienes la posición. Es ahí donde deberías hacer el setOnClickListener():

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    itemClickHandler.invoke(position)
}
```

Comment: Tenías razón, acabo de probarlo y ahora me devuelve el dato correcto. Muchas gracias.